# Mongo Aggregation does not analyze all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get some statistics using Mongo's aggregation Framework but my queries do not seem to work right. So I have a collection of documents, each document having the structure below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e46af306d0f5d63d4de6d0f"),
    "homeEmperor" : {
        "name" : "Home",
        "units" : {
            "Mage" : 15,
            "Warrior" : 15,
            "Swordmaster" : 15,
            "Rogue" : 15,
            "Warlock" : 15
        }
    },
    "awayEmperor" : {
        "name" : "Away",
        "units" : {
            "Druid" : 15,
            "Ranger" : 15,
            "Priest" : 15,
            "Monk" : 15,
            "Dragon" : 15
        }
    },
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "winner" : "away",
    "battleType" : "mutual",
    "turns" : 45,
    "_class" : "com.deathstar.Datahouse.domain.mongo.HistoricMongoRecord"
}
```

So what I'm doing at the moment is using this query to get the number of wins each unit has

```
db.getCollection('WarHistory').aggregate([
     { $match: { battleType: "mutual" } },
     { $project: {"winners": {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$winner", "home" ] }, then: "$homeEmperor.units", else: "$awayEmperor.units"} }}  },
     { $project: {"winnerUnits": { $objectToArray:  "$winners"  }}  },
     { $group: { _id: {unitType: "$winnerUnits.k"}} },
     { $unwind: "$_id.unitType" },
     { $group: { _id: {unitType: "$_id.unitType"}, count:{$sum:1} }},
     { $sort : { count : -1 }}
       ])
```

and this query to get each unit's participation

```
db.getCollection('WarHistory').aggregate([
     { $match: { battleType: "mutual" } },
     { $project: { "participants": { $mergeObjects: [ "$homeEmperor.units", "$awayEmperor.units" ] } } },
     { $project: {"participantUnits": { $objectToArray:  "$participants"  }}  },
     { $group: { _id: {unitType: "$participantUnits.k"}} },
     { $unwind: "$_id.unitType" },
     { $group: { _id: {unitType: "$_id.unitType"}, count:{$sum:1} }},
     { $sort : { count : -1 }}
       ])
```

The output of both queries is as shown below which is the way I want it:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "unitType" : "Pirate"
    },
    "count" : 1331.0
}
```

After that I divide them and so on. I also have a Java service which produces these documents.

**The problem is that while at first the queries seem to work fine, after some point they seem to stop counting all documents, so I see the "Count" counter in the Collection increasing but the query results remain exactly the same.**

I've checked and the documents continue to have the same structure along the way.

I also tried the "allowDiskUse:true" parameter in case the problem was the memory capacity(I have 16GB RAM), but it really made no difference.

Can anyone please confirm that the queries above can do what I want them to?
 Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your quieries are fine (we can reduce pipeline), but not clear what are you trying to do. What `"Priest" : 15` means? To get `"count" : 1331` you need 1331 documents... Can you share more samples to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Valijon ```"Priest" : 15``` pretty much means that there are 15 Priest units, but that is irrelevant to the aggregation and the problem. I don't think you will be able to reproduce it with just some more samples, at around 10k documents it has normal results, but after they increase it stops calculating right. I have a collection with 30k or more documents, if you're interested I could upload it somewhere

Comment: Yes please, upload it. I can't reproduce your error

Comment: @Valijon There you go, https://files.fm/u/a976rjfu. Thanks for your time.

Comment: query1: `"unitType" : "Pirate", "count" : 1331.0`, query2 `"unitType" : "Pirate",    "count" : 2099.0` ? Thats ok? Do you execute this aggregate in mongo shell or some gui, like robo3T?

Comment: Well if you see the format of my expected output, it's the same as yours, so it's not correct unfortunately. I'm running this on Robo 3T.

Comment: Can post what do you expected result? I don't see where is the error

Comment: Well I don't know the exact expected result. Here is a new collection with 55k documents. https://files.fm/f/98uawkve. If you run the query on this collection, you will  see the exact same results, which is definitely not correct.